# Why won't my form submit when I click the div inside? (Using onclick="get_form(this).submit();")

Tags: javascript, forms

I have the following form and I want to use a div to submit the form. (I have a specific reason for doing this rather than using a submit button, but that's beyond the scope of this question):

```
<form class =".functionsquestionform2" class = "classtest" action="frameworkplayground.php" method="POST">

         <input type="radio" name="functions_question2" value="1"> Question 
         </input>

         <div id="div_man" onclick="get_form(this).submit();">click me
          </div>

</form>
```

However, this doesn't work. I've also tried (unsuccessfully) to use `this.parentNode.form.submit();` instead of `get_form(this).submit();`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: what is `get_form` ?

Comment: first of all the class attribute of the form must be only one

Comment: second is onclick method should call a JS method if you wanted to do so

Comment: Thank you, @webDev. I'm completely new to coding (clearly)...how exactly would I have to change `get_form(this).submit();` to call a JS method?

Comment: @JayBlanchard The console does say "Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.onclick "

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do like following using the From ID.

```
<script>
    function submitForm(){
        document.getElementById("myFrom_id").submit();// Form submission
    }
</script>
<form class="functionsquestionform2 classtest" id="myFrom_id" action="frameworkplayground.php" method="POST">
     <input type="radio" name="functions_question2" value="1" /> Question 
     <div id="div_man" onclick="return submitForm();">click me</div>
</form>
```

Please do some research and study about basic HTML and JS on W3School.

There are many ways but this is the simple way that i prefer when you are beginner.

**Update: You can try following, it works**

```
<form class="functionsquestionform2 classtest" id="myFrom_id" action="frameworkplayground.php" method="POST">
     <input type="radio" name="functions_question2" value="1" /> Question 
     <div id="div_man" onclick='document.getElementById("myFrom_id").submit();'>click me</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I appreciate your response but is there a way to do this without having to create a separate script at the top? I'm going to have hundreds of forms so I'd rather not have to copy, paste, & modify the top script each time. I'm trying to find a simple onclick = "submit parent form" feature that will work each time I copy and paste a new form. (Side note: If only you had know how many hours of research I've done, and all that I have learned without any professional training; that's why I'm posting here - to continue learning :) )

Comment: but the problem is html can not submit your form without submit button, you need to use JS to do so. See my updated post now. On onclick() event, you have to specify the behavior of that HTML element using JS.

Comment: If you are going to have literally hundreds of forms, it may behoove you to learn some unobtrusive techniques where the script is separate. You can even share a codebase if you keep things consistent!

Comment: Actually, it didn't work. I didn't realize that I was clicking my original "submit" button. I'll post the solution that I ended up finding below. Thank you for taking the time for my question, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function () {
$("div.submitter").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().submit();
});
});
</script>
```

for this form:

```
<form class =".functionsquestionform2" class = "classtest" action="frameworkplayground.php" method="POST">

         <input type="radio" name="functions_question2" value="1"> Question 
         </input>

         <div class = "submitter">click me</div>

</form>
```

Comment: you did not want separate code, see original post. so what the meaning of posting this? and using jquery too??

Comment: No, I did not want to have to rewrite the code for each form. This uses a class so that I don't have to replace the ID for each form as the first solution would have required.

Comment: that make sense.